# Avoid unused variable for a loop in Python

Tags: python

I do this:

```
q = Queue()
runs = []
```

…

```
for i in range(0, q.qsize()):
   runs.append(q.get())
```

So the *i* variable is unused.

How do I write this correctly?

Comment: `for _ in range(...):` The `_` is used when you don't care about the value that `range` returns.

Comment: It *is* correct. By convention, though, you can use an underscore, which is probably what your linter is expecting.

Comment: Uff... you shouldn't tag this python3.x, there's nothing version specific about your question.

Comment: Does `Queue` not throw `StopIteration`?

Comment: i think you can just do for `runs = [run for run in iter(lambda: q.get(False),None)]`?

Comment: Thx everybody. I thought there was a way to do it without declaring a variable but I’ll use _ (it’s a good convention IMO)

Comment: Thx @Joran, It doesn’t seem to work, it gets stuck… Anyway I’ll try again another day.